# How do you get SID HSID information?

Tags: c#, cookies, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

Lately I've been trying to study Oauth2 and google more, but I feel stuck. It appears I'm trying to access an item that requires more information that the Oauth2 model gives against what's needed with google.

What I'm trying to do is access the bookmarks area, but each time I attempt it with the accesstoken, assuming it translates to the apisid cookie property, I get redirected to the login.

At this point I can only conclude, after reading the cookie docs at: https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/types/, that I need those other two cookie properties to pass over.

How have people tackled this in the past?

Comment: Also, I've noticed when testing, using ncrunch and nunit, that if I need to perform a login or allow an app usage (Oauth registering), that IE is forced to appear. That's odd to me because I have chrome as the default browser. Is there a way to control this behavior?

Comment: I also was looking around, and I will try something along these lines as an alternative next: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971775/youtube-and-oauth-2-0-in-net

Comment: As fas as I know, those SID and HSID cookie keys are used to control google ads by google itself (they are set in a different domain most of the time though e.g. doubleclick.net and googlesyndication.com).. I don't know why you need it.